# ¿Por que mi aplicación de laravel no sirve en otra PC?

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero instalar mi aplicación `laravel` en otra PC, no la quiero por red, no quiero enlaces, solo quiero ver si todo anda bien en otra pc desde 0.

La instalar en una laptop que tengo, instale `Xampp` (active el driver de `postgresql`), `Composer` y `Postgresql`, las mismas versiones que uso en la PC donde estoy programando la aplicación.

Me inicia sesión, todo se ve bien pero al intentar hacer modificación a la BD como `CREATE, UPDATE o DELETE` me lanza error y no hace nada, la console de chrome me dice: `http://localhost:8000/18`

**Actualización 1:**

Acá la imagen que me arroja el ajax en la parte de:

```
error: function(data) {
      console.debug(data.responseText)
}
```

[image: Imagen del error]

**Actualización 2**

Elimine los middleware y funciona todo correctamente.

Acá un ejemplo de uno de los middleware que uso:

```
auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ruta){
        $results = DB::select("select exists(select * FROM perfiles_funciones AS pf INNER JOIN funciones AS f ON f.id = pf.id_funciones INNER JOIN perfiles AS p ON p.id = pf.id_perfiles WHERE pf.id_perfiles = :id AND f.id = :ruta AND pf.crear = 't')",
            [
            'id' => ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles),
            'ruta'=>($ruta)
            ]);
        if($results){
            //session()->set('message','No tiene permisos para Crear');
            $ruta = strtolower($ruta);
            return redirect('/'.$ruta);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Los paso en cada controlador con un parametro, de la siguiente manera:

```
        $this->middleware('ruta:18');
        $this->middleware('crear:18',['only'=>['crear']]);
        $this->middleware('modificar:18',['only'=>['editar']]);
        $this->middleware('eliminar:18',['only'=>['eliminar']]);
        $this->middleware('estado:18',['only'=>['estado']]);
```

Actualización 3:

Acá en enlace del código que arroja el debug en el error.

[Enlace del .html](https://mega.nz/#!A45ElLYL!tWbqRDd7mDAPtKGAOOrk5f46gPfzMC9syxXZiWnCC-8)

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra?

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico con el error que te sale y, sobre todo, cualquier otra información que te ofrezca el log de error del servidor apache?

Comment: @x4mp73r Actualizado

Comment: @OscarGarcia actualizado

Comment: si estas en debug, puedes darle click al error donde arroja el 500 desde chrome y darle en la ventanita de preview, para poder debugear mejor tu error

Comment: Ese error 500 es un error en el código PHP que no se muestra al cliente, se guarda en el log de error, ¿podrías facilitar lo que te pedí? ¿podrías poner qué te sale en el log de error del servidor apache?

Comment: @OscarGarcia ¿como obtengo ese error que dices?

Comment: Aunque ya determine que el error son los middleware, pero debe ser algo de laravel porque los middleware me funcionan perfectamente en esta PC con el mismo usuario, y utilizado migrate --seed para la base de datos, asi que esta exactamente igual en la laptop en que estoy probando la aplicacion.

Comment: Es lo que te he dicho, sólo podrás averiguar qué está pasando analizando el log de error. Si así te funciona, entonces perfecto :) si quieres averiguar por qué no te funcionan los middleware, entonces adelante con la investigación, te seguiré echando una mano.

Comment: si quiero averiguar porque no me funcionan los middleware, ya que son parte de la seguridad del sistema. Lo que no se es como obtengo el error que tu quieres ver. De lo que retorna el ajax, que quieres ver? error: function(data) {
      console.debug(data.responseText)
}

Comment: @PabloContreras , tu servidor apache guarda logs en dos archivos: uno es el log normal (`CustomLog`) y otro es el log de error (`ErrorLog`). En linux (lo siento, no sé cómo está configurado en windows) el log normal suele guardarse, por ejemplo, en `/var/log/apache2/access.log` y el de error en `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Allí es donde van a parar los mensajes de error y advertencia que no son mostrados/enviados al navegador del cliente (por ejemplo, los detalles que generan ese error 500 tan molesto que sufres).